# Allow table to expand over max-width in Google Chrome

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with `max-width: 300px;`. In Mozilla Firefox, IE, and Opera, if the content of the table is wider than 300 px, it tries to break it. If it can't be broken, it allows the table to resize over 300 px. How can I achieve this behaviour in Google Chrome?

Edit:

```
<table style="max-width: 300px; background-color: yellow;">
  <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer euismod nibh amet Vestibulum ornare. Natoque convallis auctor arcu ac.</td></tr>
  <tr><td>LoremipsumdolorsitametconsectetuereuismodnibhametVestibulumornareNatoqueconvallisauctorarcuac.</td></tr>
</table>
```

In Firefox the table is 625 px wide. The text is dynamically generated.

Comment: show us the code you've got please

Comment: Can't understand why you use max-width if you don't want max-width to work. Maybe using width instead or a combination with min-width would help?

Comment: Because I don't want to limit the minimal width.

Comment: then probably you want to use `min-width` instead of `max-width`?

Comment: I said what I want. I don't want `min-width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following style to the table or the cells

```
word-break: break-all;
```

This will force the work to break even if it does not have spaces and not break the tables width, and it wont force you to set a min-width / width on the table either.

Edit:

This should give you the desired behavior:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width: auto;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style= "max-width: 300px">
        <table style="background-color: yellow;">
            <tr class="text"><td><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer euismod nibh amet Vestibulum ornare. Natoque convallis auctor arcu ac.</div></td></tr>
            <tr class="text"><td>  
                 LoremipsumdolorsitametconsectetuereuismodnibhametVestibulumornareNatoqueconvallisauctorarcuac.
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I use this as a temporal solution, but it is not what I want.

Comment: Why do u still want to use max width if u want the browser to not obey the same?

Comment: I have edited my answer above, this will give yu the desired behavior in chrome browser